# send mail to specific people in group via discussion

Tags: 2010

i need to create a discussion forum where i need to create a post and send email to only specific people in the group . hw can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you do it via a choice column for the post category and based on the selection, a workflow will send an email to the desired people?

So if choice = marketing, email Jim and Sue, if choice = IT email Bob, Jeff, and Jane, etc

Comment: right now i have used a discussion library .
i create a new discussion and also i have added the "Assigned To" column where i specify the people who wil take part in discussion .
nw i need to send mail to all people who are specified in the "Assigned to " field . i am planning to use itemadd event handler . it there any other option ?

Comment: Using a workflow in SharePoint Designer that fires on item creation.